# HIVE on TEZ (java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support)

Tags: hive, snappy, tez

My script keeps falling with the same error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support
```

The code itself looks like this

```
WITH step1 AS(
  SELECT columns
  FROM t1 stg
  WHERE time_key < '2017-04-08' AND time_key >= DATE_ADD('2017-04-08', -31)
  GROUP BY columns
  HAVING conditions1
)
, step2 AS(
  SELECT columns
  FROM t2
  WHERE conditions2
)
, step3 AS(
  SELECT columns
  FROM stg
  JOIN comverse_sub
  ON conditions3
)
INSERT INTO TABLE t1 PARTITION(time_key = '2017-04-08')
SELECT columns
FROM step3
WHERE conditions4
```

I checked if there is snappy installed

```
hadoop checknative -a
```

and got

```
snappy:  true /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/hadoop/lib/native/libsnappy.so.1
```

My settings for tez are

```
set tez.queue.name=adhoc;
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
set hive.tez.container.size=4096;
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.tez.auto.reducer.parallelism=true;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET tez.runtime.compress=true;
SET tez.runtime.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
```

I should also note that not all script on tez fail. Some work. Like this one

```
WITH hist AS(
  SELECT columns
  FROM t1
  WHERE conditions1
)
INSERT INTO TABLE t1 PARTITION(time_key)
SELECT columns
FROM hist
INNER JOIN t2
  on conditions2
INNER JOIN t3
  ON conditions3
WHERE conditions4
```

Why does this happen?

I checked [this](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.6/bk_installing_manually_book/content/ref-ffec9e6b-41f4-47de-b5cd-1403b4c4a7c8.1.html) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/22419/hive-on-tez-performance-tuning-determining-reducer.html) and [this](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/introduction_compression_snappy.html#concept_cy3_snz_pv). Didn't help. Also, when I run the scripts on MR they all work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it. I just kept adding settings untill it worked. Still don't know what the problem was and the solution is not very good, but it'll do for the time being.

```
set tez.queue.name=adhoc;
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
set hive.tez.container.size=4096;
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.tez.auto.reducer.parallelism=true;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET tez.runtime.compress=true;
SET tez.runtime.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
SET das.reduce-tasks-per-node=12;
SET das.map-tasks-per-node=12;
SET das.job.map-task.memory=4096;
SET das.job.reduce-task.memory=4096;
SET das.job.application-manager.memory=4096;
SET tez.runtime.io.sort.mb=512;
SET tez.runtime.io.sort.factor=100;
set hive.tez.min.partition.factor=0.25;
set hive.tez.max.partition.factor=2.0;
set mapred.reduce.tasks = -1;
```